# Recognizer not working efficiently after adding more words in grammar of sphinx 4

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

i have increased the size of grammar and hence added many more words in the dictionary with different accents by using different HMMs. But the recognizer is not working efficiently and taking absurd words or may not respond. It is happening mostly with large words added in grammar. for example i added word like stackoverflow in grammar and made entry in the dictionary too. But its not recognizing it.
Pls help.

Comment: To get help on accuracy issues you need to provide a test database. For more information see CMUSphinx FAQ http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor

Comment: What acoustic model are you using? Have you trained your own? Are you sure you are adding words to dictionary properly? Is their phonetic representation accurate?

Comment: do you have any solution for same? Please help me